# drupal 8 - how to serve up static files

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

Is there a way to define a portion of the filesystem in Drupal 8 that is served up as static files so I can just link to the file as if it was in a plain ol' html site?

For an example of what I mean, if I have this on the page:

```
link rel="import" href="modules/webcomponenttest/web_component/from-scratch.html"
```

Is there a way to make it so that the whole `web_component` folder is served up as static files (not processed by Drupal)?  The reason is because the `from-scratch.html` file itself contains rel="import" elements for files relative to it.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal doesn't care much about what Apache (or your web server of choice) is serving directly (or statically). So depending on the situation I would place the static files in `/sites/SITE/files/static` or even right at the root `/static` if it's a big project where I choose to go without multisite.

When migrating to Drupal from another platform this is great since you can keep the same paths for your files (usually images) so you don't loose link juice.

I'm not sure what the `rel="import"` stuff is about but with Drupal you can also directly serve `.php` files that don't have anything to do with Drupal, I guess this `rel="import"` stuff is very similar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Kasper.  The way you suggested is how I'm doing it now, but I was hoping that I could package up some static files (HTML 5 web components) along with my module without having to add tons of routes, etc.